# THREEjs - crop texture instead of stretching-to-fit

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm attempting to build an image-based art-making app using three.js.

I'm using React.js, but hopefully the following is clear even for those without React experience. The component renders a , and it's passed a locally-hosted image URL from a parent component.

The current code is set up to simply create a full-window canvas, create a 2D shape that spans the entire canvas, and set the provided image as a texture:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

const vertexShader = `
  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {
      vUv = uv;
      gl_Position = vec4(uv * 2. - vec2(1, 1), 0., 1.);
  }
`;

const fragmentShader = `
  precision highp float;

  varying vec2 vUv;
  uniform sampler2D texture1;
  void main() {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, vUv.xy);
  }
`;

class Canvas extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // TODO: resize handlers for width/height
    const {width, height} = this.state;

    this.canvas.width = width;
    this.canvas.height = height;

    const rendererParams = {
      canvas: this.canvas,
    };
    const cameraParams = [
      -width / 2,
      width / 2,
      -height / 2,
      height / 2,
    ];

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(rendererParams);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF, 1.0)
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);

    this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(...cameraParams);
    this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 200);

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.add(this.camera);

    // Our initial texture will be the specified default image.
    const imageSrc = this.props.defaultImageSrc;

    textureLoader.load(imageSrc, texture => {
      this.texture = texture;

      // TODO: Do I need this?
      this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader,
        fragmentShader,
        uniforms: {
          texture1: {
            type: "t",
            value: this.texture
          }
        }
      });

      this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1), this.material);

      this.scene.add(this.mesh);

      this.animate();
    })
  }

  animate = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <canvas innerRef={elem => this.canvas = elem} />
    );
  }
}

export default Canvas;
```

The issue I'm having is that the texture will be stretched to fit. This means that if the image is a square 1600x1600, but the browser window is 1000x500, the image will be squashed and distorted, since it's mapping the image to fit perfectly in the available space:

[image: squashed woman]

What I want is an equivalent of `background-size: cover`. I want it to shrink to the largest window dimension (1000x1000, in my example), and then crop from the center to only show the middle 500px worth of height.

Comment: You need to show your camera, are you using a `PerspectiveCamera`, an `OrthographicCamera` or a place holder `Camera`. And, if you're using a custom shader you need to show how you calculate your vertex positions (do you they use `projectionMatrix` or not. Without that knowledge no one can answer the question

Comment: Hey @gman, thanks for your help! My bad for assuming that the camera and shaders weren't necessary

Answer (score 2):

You need to show your camera, are you using a `PerspectiveCamera`, an `OrthographicCamera` or a place holder `Camera`. And, if you're using a custom shader you need to show how you calculate your vertex positions (do you they use `projectionMatrix` or not etc...). Without that knowledge no one can answer the question.

Here's how to do it using an `OrthographicCamera` just set to become the identity matrix and a 2 unit `PlaneGeometry`.

If we changed nothing else this would display a plane that fills the canvas. After that we scale it taking into account the aspect of the canvas and the aspect of the image

```
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const image = material.map.image;
  const canvasAspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
  const imageAspect = image.width / image.height;

  // this assumes we want to fill vertically
  let horizontalDrawAspect = imageAspect / canvasAspect;
  let verticalDrawAspect = 1;
  // does it fill horizontally?
  if (horizontalDrawAspect < 1) {
    // no it does not so scale so we fill horizontally and
    // adjust vertical to match
    verticalDrawAspect /= horizontalDrawAspect;
    horizontalDrawAspect = 1;
  }
  mesh.scale.x = horizontalDrawAspect;
  mesh.scale.y = verticalDrawAspect;
```

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

camera.position.z = 1;

function render() {
  resize();
  
  if (!material.map.image) {
    return;
  }
  
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const image = material.map.image;
  const canvasAspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
  const imageAspect = image.width / image.height;
  
  // this assumes we want to fill vertically
  let horizontalDrawAspect = imageAspect / canvasAspect;
  let verticalDrawAspect = 1;
  // does it fill horizontally?
  if (horizontalDrawAspect < 1) {
    // no it does not so scale so we fill horizontally and
    // adjust vertical to match
    verticalDrawAspect /= horizontalDrawAspect;
    horizontalDrawAspect = 1;
  }
  mesh.scale.x = horizontalDrawAspect;
  mesh.scale.y = verticalDrawAspect;

  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function resize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) { 
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', render);

const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = "";

// load a resource
loader.load('http://i.imgur.com/TSiyiJv.jpg', function (texture) {
  texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
  texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
  texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
  material.map = texture;
  render();
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Updated my snippet - I am indeed using an `OrthographicCamera`. I'm using a custom vertex shader simply because I had trouble getting an image to render without it, but I'll give MeshBasicMaterial another shot. Thanks so much for your input, I really appreciate it.